# HTML element not positioned in the same place on my domain (and others' localhost) as my localhost

Tags: html, css, sass, web, frontend

I have been developing the front-end of a website for a company me and a few others are running. I am using the materializecss library for a carousel. With some slight modifications with custom styling I produced this:
[Localhost view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj6BA.jpg)

I pushed this Github for my friend to pull. He stuck it up on the domain but the carousel looked like this: [Domain view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z4In.jpg). He ran it on his localhost and received the same result.

The section's HTML, scss and js:

```
//Initialise
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
h3#portfolio-title {
    font-family: 'Bungee Shade', cursive;
    left: calc((100vw - 310px) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    @include header-underline($blackBg, 10px, 2px, solid);
}

.carousel {
    height: 600px !important;
}
.carousel .carousel-item {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-top: calc((100vh - 450px) / 2);
}
div.pf-option-btn {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
div.webs-content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 200vh;
}
.lean-overlay {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
<h3 id="portfolio-title">Portfolio</h3>

<div id="webs-content" class="modal webs-content-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pf-options-container container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-item" class="center">
            <img src="../public/images/phone-ws.png" />
            <div class="pf-option-btn center">
              <button data-target="webs-content" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange modal-trigger">View Websites</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- carousel-item was an <a> but I changed it to <div> as a test - no impact -->

        <a class="carousel-item" class="center"><img src="../public/images/laptop-code.png" />

        </a>

        <a class="carousel-item" class="center"><img src="../public/images/notepad-shapes-ws.png" />

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used Diff Checker to make sure what was pushed to Github was identical to what I had on my end, and it was. All suggestions on how to fix this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same browser version?

Check the console on the browser, maybe some requests are missing on your friend's computer.

Comment: I checked and, yes, we are on the same version of Chrome. I've been able to find a temporary fix that displays the way intended on most browsers. Materializecss needed to have some of its classes' heights and widths overwritten. Thanks for replying.